# whats is difference between dbms_scheduler and dbms_parallel_execute

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I would like to know what is the difference between dbms_scheduler and dbms_parallel_execute.

currently i have big table , first i want to select data which not exists in my big table by join check with another table and insert to my big table . since the number of records could be more then 1m i thinking to run in parallel to make it faster the process and performance, but im confused with  dbms_scheduler and dbms_parallel_execute.

Please suggest me which one is useful for my situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DBMS_SCHEDULER` package provides a collection of `scheduling` functions and procedures that are callable from any PL/SQL program. Read more at [DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#CIHIGGBB)

The `DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE` package allows a workload associated with a base table to be **broken down into smaller chunks** which can be run in parallel. Read more at : [DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/dbms_parallel_execute_11gR2)

In your case , i would suggest you to use `Merge` statment which would be faster in anycase rather that checking first and then inserting in 2 different steps. Read more about Merge at : [Merge](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606)

Comment: thank you for the answer , anyhow can u achieve this using DBMS_SCHEDULER  or DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE (parallel insert) ?

Comment: Try `DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE` ..read more how to do that at the link provided.